# PowerShell Email with Text Input

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to write a script that will throw up four text input boxes and save their entered values into four variables, each representing Username, Phone PIN, Voicemail PIN and Phone extension - Once populated, it sends the email, which itself uses said variables as placeholders where each value must appear.

I've obscured and deleted some of the code for anonymity, however I hope it still reads logically.

The script partially works, but with a bizarre flaw that I cannot identify.

When **initially** executed, the script throws up the 4 text input boxes and successfully does a Write-Host, displaying the result of the data entered into the text input boxes (E.g. fred.bloggs, 1000, 1000, 1000) - Proving that the user-entered data IS being saved into the variables. It then sends the email, but ALL of the variable fields are blank when I receive the email. (I'm testing by putting my own username into the Username input box.)

If I run the script a **second** time, the script throws up the 4 boxes, does successful write-host showing the **new** values (E.g. fred.bloggs, 1001, 1001, 1001) saved against each variable, then sends the email - But, the email contains the values I entered when I **first** ran the script. (fred.blogs, 1000, 1000, 1000)

So I get blank variables in the email output when I run it the first time (E.g. If I close Powershell_ISE and re-open). And I get the previous values entered if I run it a second time. It seems like whenever I run the script, it always sends the email using the values of the previous attempt.

So it's like this:

Attempt 1: 
Entered fred.bloggs, 1000, 1000, 1000 - Result: all blank in email variable fields

Attempt 2: 
Entered fred.bloggs, 1001, 1001, 1001 - Result: Email variable fields populated with fred.bloggs, 1000, 1000, 1000

Attempt 3: 
Entered fred.bloggs, 1002, 1002, 1002 - Result: Email variable fields populated with fred.bloggs, 1001, 1001, 1001

I suspect it's down to the way the text input box values are being saved against the variables, but I can't find the fault.

Code is as below. Any help would be immensely appreciated as I am very much learning from scratch with Powershell.

```
$EmailFrom = "obscured@obscured.com"
$EmailSubject = "Welcome to obscured + On-Boarding Details"
$SMTPServer = "obscured"
$SMTPPassword = Get-Content .\mailpw.txt | ConvertTo-SecureString
$SMTPCred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential "MailUser",
$SMTPPassword
$EmailBody = @"

Hi $StarterName,

Log in with obscured\$StarterName

Your Personalised details:
Username: $StarterName<Br>
Email:  $StarterName@obscured.com<Br>
Phone Extension: $PhoneExt (+obscured $PhoneExt) Dial 0 for external calls.    <Br>
Phone Username: $StarterName<Br>
Phone PIN: $PhonePin <Br>
Voicemail PIN: $VMPin <Br>

"@

#INPUT BOX: STARTER USER NAME

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing

$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$form.Text = 'Data Entry Form'
$form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(300,200)
$form.StartPosition = 'CenterScreen'

$OKButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$OKButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(75,120)
$OKButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$OKButton.Text = 'OK'
$OKButton.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK
$form.AcceptButton = $OKButton
$form.Controls.Add($OKButton)

$CancelButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$CancelButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(150,120)
$CancelButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$CancelButton.Text = 'Cancel'
$CancelButton.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::Cancel
$form.CancelButton = $CancelButton
$form.Controls.Add($CancelButton)

$label = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$label.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,20)
$label.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,20)
$label.Text = 'Enter Starter UserName:'
$form.Controls.Add($label)

$textBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$textBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,40)
$textBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(260,20)
$form.Controls.Add($textBox)

$form.Topmost = $true

$form.Add_Shown({$textBox.Select()})
$result = $form.ShowDialog()

if ($result -eq [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK)
{
    $StarterName = $textBox.Text
    $StarterName
}

#INPUT BOX: PHONE EXTENSION

$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$form.Text = 'Data Entry Form'
$form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(300,200)
$form.StartPosition = 'CenterScreen'

$OKButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$OKButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(75,120)
$OKButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$OKButton.Text = 'OK'
$OKButton.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK
$form.AcceptButton = $OKButton
$form.Controls.Add($OKButton)

$CancelButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$CancelButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(150,120)
$CancelButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$CancelButton.Text = 'Cancel'
$CancelButton.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::Cancel
$form.CancelButton = $CancelButton
$form.Controls.Add($CancelButton)

$label = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$label.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,20)
$label.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,20)
$label.Text = 'Enter Starter Phone Extension'
$form.Controls.Add($label)

$textBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$textBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,40)
$textBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(260,20)
$form.Controls.Add($textBox)

$form.Topmost = $true

$form.Add_Shown({$textBox.Select()})
$result = $form.ShowDialog()

if ($result -eq [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK)
{
    $PhoneExt = $textBox.Text
    $PhoneExt
}

#INPUT BOX: PHONE PIN

$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$form.Text = 'Data Entry Form'
$form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(300,200)
$form.StartPosition = 'CenterScreen'

$OKButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$OKButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(75,120)
$OKButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$OKButton.Text = 'OK'
$OKButton.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK
$form.AcceptButton = $OKButton
$form.Controls.Add($OKButton)

$CancelButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$CancelButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(150,120)
$CancelButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$CancelButton.Text = 'Cancel'
$CancelButton.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::Cancel
$form.CancelButton = $CancelButton
$form.Controls.Add($CancelButton)

$label = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$label.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,20)
$label.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,20)
$label.Text = 'Enter Starter Phone PIN:'
$form.Controls.Add($label)

$textBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$textBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,40)
$textBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(260,20)
$form.Controls.Add($textBox)

$form.Topmost = $true

$form.Add_Shown({$textBox.Select()})
$result = $form.ShowDialog()

if ($result -eq [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK)
{
    $PhonePIN = $textBox.Text
    $PhonePIN
}

#INPUT BOX: VM PIN

$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$form.Text = 'Data Entry Form'
$form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(300,200)
$form.StartPosition = 'CenterScreen'

$OKButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$OKButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(75,120)
$OKButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$OKButton.Text = 'OK'
$OKButton.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK
$form.AcceptButton = $OKButton
$form.Controls.Add($OKButton)

$CancelButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$CancelButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(150,120)
$CancelButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$CancelButton.Text = 'Cancel'
$CancelButton.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::Cancel
$form.CancelButton = $CancelButton
$form.Controls.Add($CancelButton)

$label = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$label.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,20)
$label.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,20)
$label.Text = 'Enter Starter Voicemail PIN:'
$form.Controls.Add($label)

$textBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$textBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,40)
$textBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(260,20)
$form.Controls.Add($textBox)

$form.Topmost = $true

$form.Add_Shown({$textBox.Select()})
$result = $form.ShowDialog()

if ($result -eq [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK)
{
    $VMPin = $textBox.Text
    $VMPin
}


Write-Host "Sending email to $StarterName@obscured.com" -ForegroundColor Green
Write-Host "PhoneExt: $PhoneExt" -ForegroundColor Green
Write-Host "Phone PIN: $PhonePIN" -ForegroundColor Green
Write-Host "Voicemail PIN: $VMPin" -ForegroundColor Green

Send-MailMessage -Credential $SMTPCred -To "$StarterName@obscured" -From 
$EmailFrom -Subject $EmailSubject -SmtpServer $SMTPServer -Body $EmailBody -BodyAsHtml
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know Powershell, but I guess variables are interpolated into string when it is defined, not used.

Move `$EmailBody` definition down, below data input code.

Subsequent runs work, but with outdated values, because variables are persisted between executions by shell.

Answer (score 4):

Why do this is 4 dialog boxes vs a single GUI instance?

What you are doing is really overkill for what you are after

The reason you are getting the previous variable data in the ISE, is because you did not clear them before you used them again, they are still in memory.

Populated variables do not auto clear. So, you have to explicitly empty them as well as exit, close garbage collect any stuff you instantiated or restart the ISE / dev environment which is just a do over of everything anyway.

Whether you use a form or not, you should always clean up / clear delete stuff like that before it can be used again. This can happen with any programming language, so not a PS specific thing or ISE specific thing.

All this sounds like you are new to PS GUI development or app dev in general. There are lots of videos on YouTube that cover PS GUI creation and useage with WPF and WinForms as well as lots of articles all over the web.

You don't even need a customized form, unless you are doing some branding.
You could just do this.

Use a simplistic PS GUI (Using the Show-Command cmdlet) and input the info that when you click run, sends that to the Send-MailMessage cmdlet as a function. The only drawbacks here are, it's functional, not pretty, and you cannot order the params. Hence my branding point above.

Example:

```
function New-UserOnboardingEmail
    {
        param
        (
            [Parameter(Mandatory)]
            [string]$Username,

            [Parameter(Mandatory)]
            [string]$PhonePin,

            [Parameter(Mandatory)]
            [string]$VoicemailPin,

            [Parameter(Mandatory)]
            [string]$PhoneExt
        )


        $UserOnBoardDetails =  "
        UserName  : $Username`n
        PhonePin  : $PhonePin`n
        VoiceMail : $VoicemailPin`n
        PhoneExt  : $PhoneExt"

        Send-MailMessage `
        -From "$Admin@domain.com" `
        -To "$Username@domain.com" `
        -Subject 'Welcome to obscured + On-Boarding Details' `
        -Body: $UserOnBoardDetails `
        -SmtpServer $SmtpServer `
        -Encoding UTF8 `
        -Credential $Creds
    }

Show-Command -Name New-UserOnboardingEmail
```

As for doing this in one form, use https://poshgui.com, drag and drop form designer then just attach your code behind to make it take action.

As for your code, you have to pass the value of the textbox entry to be able to use that on a button click event.

Example using that online gui designer

```
<# This form was created using POSHGUI.com  a free online gui designer for PowerShell
.NAME
    Untitled
#>

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()

#region begin GUI{ 

$frmUserOnBoarding               = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Form
$frmUserOnBoarding.ClientSize    = '400,400'
$frmUserOnBoarding.text          = "New User On-boarding "
$frmUserOnBoarding.TopMost       = $false

$lblUserName                     = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Label
$lblUserName.text                = "UserName"
$lblUserName.AutoSize            = $true
$lblUserName.width               = 25
$lblUserName.height              = 10
$lblUserName.location            = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(17,22)
$lblUserName.Font                = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'

$txtUserName                     = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$txtUserName.multiline           = $false
$txtUserName.width               = 100
$txtUserName.height              = 20
$txtUserName.location            = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(157,17)
$txtUserName.Font                = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'

$lblPhonePin                     = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Label
$lblPhonePin.text                = "PhonePin"
$lblPhonePin.AutoSize            = $true
$lblPhonePin.width               = 25
$lblPhonePin.height              = 10
$lblPhonePin.location            = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(17,60)
$lblPhonePin.Font                = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'

$txtPhonePin                     = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$txtPhonePin.multiline           = $false
$txtPhonePin.width               = 100
$txtPhonePin.height              = 20
$txtPhonePin.location            = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(156,51)
$txtPhonePin.Font                = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'

$lblVoicemailPin                 = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Label
$lblVoicemailPin.text            = "VoiceMailPin"
$lblVoicemailPin.AutoSize        = $true
$lblVoicemailPin.width           = 25
$lblVoicemailPin.height          = 10
$lblVoicemailPin.location        = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(18,94)
$lblVoicemailPin.Font            = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'

$txtVoicemailPin                 = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$txtVoicemailPin.multiline       = $false
$txtVoicemailPin.width           = 100
$txtVoicemailPin.height          = 20
$txtVoicemailPin.location        = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(157,88)
$txtVoicemailPin.Font            = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'

$lblPhoneExt                     = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Label
$lblPhoneExt.text                = "PhoneExt"
$lblPhoneExt.AutoSize            = $true
$lblPhoneExt.width               = 25
$lblPhoneExt.height              = 10
$lblPhoneExt.location            = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(20,126)
$lblPhoneExt.Font                = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'

$txtPhoneExt                     = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$txtPhoneExt.multiline           = $false
$txtPhoneExt.width               = 100
$txtPhoneExt.height              = 20
$txtPhoneExt.location            = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(154,124)
$txtPhoneExt.Font                = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'

$btnSubmit                       = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Button
$btnSubmit.text                  = "Submit"
$btnSubmit.width                 = 60
$btnSubmit.height                = 30
$btnSubmit.location              = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(16,168)
$btnSubmit.Font                  = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'

$btnCancel                       = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Button
$btnCancel.text                  = "Cancel"
$btnCancel.width                 = 60
$btnCancel.height                = 30
$btnCancel.location              = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(87,167)
$btnCancel.Font                  = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'

$frmUserOnBoarding.controls.AddRange(@($lblUserName,$txtUserName,$lblPhonePin,$txtPhonePin,$lblVoicemailPin,$txtVoicemailPin,$lblPhoneExt,$txtPhoneExt,$btnSubmit,$btnCancel))

#region gui events {
$btnSubmit.Add_Click({ 
$UserName = $txtUserName.Text
$PhonePin = $txtPhonePin.Text
$VoicemailPin = $txtVoicemailPin.Text
$PhoneExt = $txtPhoneExt.Text 
$frmUserOnBoarding.Close()})
#endregion events }

#endregion GUI }


#Write your logic code here

[void]$frmUserOnBoarding.ShowDialog()


# Results from the submit button on the form
$UserName
$PhonePin
$VoicemailPin
$PhoneExt
```

Comment: I have placed the $MessageBody content, which contains the user-input variables, below where the variables are declared - In my original script, this successfully solved the original problem I posted - In another script, I did the same but it still has the original problem. I can't see what is different that would be causing this. I've implemented every method of remove-variable or clear-variable that I could find online, yet none seem to eliminate this problem.